# How can I count lines in my program files (multiple), filtering some file and some lines?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bunch of code files I've selected with a `find` command.

I need to count lines of code but filtering out lines I don't care about – namely all the `import` statements.

How can I do this in bash?

Here's what I have so far:

```
function codecount { find . -name "$@" | grep -v test | xargs wc -l; }
```

So if I run `codecount *.java` it will find all my Java files, eliminating any that are test code, then count the lines.  I want to further refine this to filter out the "import" lines on the remaining files before the line count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is *almost* possible using only grep:

```
grep -r --include='*.java' --exclude='*test*' -vch '^import' *
```

This does the following:

- `-r`: recursively search through all subdirectories
- `--include='*.java'`: only grep files ending with `.java`
- `--exclude-'*test*'`: ... but exclude files where the name contains `test`
- `-v '^import'`: invert match, exclude lines starting with `import`
- `-c`: count matches instead of returning them (counts per line)
- `-h`: suppress output of file names, just print number of matches

This returns something like

```
2
3
5
```

and we just want the total. Instead of piping to `| paste -s -d '+' | bc` or even `| awk '{sum += $1} END { print sum }'`, we can go one step back, have the matching lines printed and then count them with `wc`:

```
grep -r --include='*.java' --exclude='*test*' -vh '^import' * | wc -l
```

This can be turned into a function where the parameter determines what should be included, we just have be careful with quoting:

```
codecount () {
    grep -r --include="$1" --exclude='*test*' -vh '^import' * | wc -l
}
```

This has to be called like

```
codecount '*.java'
```

to avoid expansion of the `*` before being used in the function.

---

**Minimal change to OP's solution:**

If you really want to use `find`, `grep` and `xargs`, you could modify your try like this:

```
codecount () {
    find . -name "$@" | grep -v test | xargs grep -v '^import' | wc -l
}
```

I've just added one `grep -v` step to filter lines starting with `import` (and replaced `function codecount` with `codecount ()` for improved portability).

Notice that this *still* needs to be called with quotes on the command line:

```
codecount '*.java'
```

---

**`find -exec cat` and `grep`:**

A last solution: using `find` to filter file names containing `test` instead of `xargs grep -v`, then `cat` so grep doesn't see the file names:

```
find -type f -name '*.java' -not -name '*test*' -exec cat {} \; |
grep -vc '^import'
```

This can be made into a function just like the other two examples, and the quoting remark still applies.

Answer (score 1):

In Bash, you can use `globstar` together with `extglob`:

```
shopt -s extglob
shopt -s globstar

codecount() {
    grep -v ^import **/!(test*).java | wc -l
}
```

Explaination:

- `grep -v ^import <file-list>` prints all lines from `<file-list>` except those starting with `import`.
- `**/!(test*).java` can be decomposed into three parts:

  - `**` is used to match all files in the current directory and in subdirectories;
  - `!(test*)` means: everything except those files starting with `test`;
  - `.java`: everything that ends with `.java`

  So, in the end, it'll match all Java files except those starting with `test`.
- `wc -l` counts lines.

Note that it counts blank lines too. If you want to exclude blank lines, then use:

```
grep -v -e "^import" -e "^$" **/!(test*).java | wc -l
```

Comment: `globstar` is very elegant, but now it doesn't exclude file names containing `test` as per the OP's example.

Comment: @BenjaminW.: thanks, I didn't see he wanted to exclude names containing `test`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest consider using [ag](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) instead of `grep`.

It's created for this usage, and it's faster than grep, since it automatically ignores binary files and `.git` folders etc. It also have lots of useful extra options.

List file paths with import and the matching line count in each file

```
ag import --java --count
```

Detailed summary

```
ag import --java --stats
```

You can of course also search by regex. I think this will give the result you are looking for, by using invert-match to only show non-matching lines, and nogroup to not add gaps and headers for each file.

```
ag '(^import|test)' --invert-match --java --nogroup | wc -l
```